# Getting custom post type meta on publish

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to get the Custom Post Meta on publishing the post? I tried this:

```
function get_cpt_meta($post_ID) {
 $post = get_post($post_ID);
 $meta = get_post_custom(); 
         $mfname = $meta['f_name'][0];
         $mlname = $meta['l_name'][0];
         echo $mfname. " " . $mlname;
}
add_action('publish_book', 'get_cpt_meta');
```

and

```
function get_cpt_meta($post_ID) {
 $post = get_post($post_ID);
 $meta = get_post_custom($post); 
         $mfname = $meta['f_name'][0];
         $mlname = $meta['l_name'][0];
         echo $mfname. " " . $mlname;
}
add_action('publish_book', 'get_cpt_meta');
```

Comment: I gave a [recent answer on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945/472495) about egregious pleading in answers, and how it can affect responses to your questions (including downvoting or lack of replies). Please read it when you get a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look as below:

```
function get_cpt_meta($post_id){
  $f_name = get_post_meta($post_id,'f_name');
  $l_name = get_post_meta($post_id,'l_name');
  echo $mfname. " " . $mlname;      
}
add_action('save_post','get_cpt_meta',11,1);
```